# Dividing video into parts on Android

Tags: java, android, asp.net, video, upload

I am trying to send a video to an asp.net server on android. However, since the video size is about 26 MB I am not able to send the video? Is there a way to divide the video into parts and send them to the .net server via android by using java?

```
 import java.io.DataOutputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.provider.MediaStore;
 import android.util.Log;

 public class VideoUploader extends Activity 
 {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public static final int SELECT_VIDEO=1;
public static final String TAG="UploadActivity";
String path="";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    openGaleryVideo();
}

public void openGaleryVideo()
{
    Intent intent=new Intent();
    intent.setType("video/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Video"),SELECT_VIDEO);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_VIDEO) {
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();
            path= getPath(videoUri);
            doFileUpload();
        } 
    }
}
public String getPath(Uri uri)
{   
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}

public void doFileUpload()
{
        String pathToOurFile = path;//this will be the file path        
        String urlServer = "http://192.168.10.177/androidweb/default.aspx";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 2*1024* 1024;

        try
        {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile));

        URL url = new URL(urlServer);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Allow Inputs & Outputs
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        // Enable POST method
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",  "multipart/form-data");
        connection.setRequestProperty("SD-FileName", "Chrysanthemum.JPEG");

        DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // Read file
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }//end of while statement

         int serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
         String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
         Log.d("ServerCode",""+serverResponseCode);
         Log.d("serverResponseMessage",""+serverResponseMessage);
         fileInputStream.close();
         outputStream.flush();
         outputStream.close();
        }//end of try body

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error: ", ex.getMessage());
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if the video doesn't need to be playable until re-assembled, just send so many bytes in each piece and have the server re-assemble it.   The rest of this will assume that you need to divide it into a number of videos which *can* be played individually.

You might look at the video editing example in the ICS, though depending on how it is implement that might confine you to the latest devices.

Otherwise:

Most compressed video formats can be thought of as a repeating sequence of absolute information (keyframe) followed by relative information for frames encoded relative to that base.  If you learn about the details of the unspecified format you are using, you can probably learn how to identify a place near the size where you wish to cut where a new section begins with a full key frame.  You would split the video there, creating any necessary file header in the new part, and adjusting any length information in the original header.

While doing this yourself would be educational, it would also be worth looking for existing solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but could you please give me the link of the video editing example in the ICS?

Comment: In addition I am getting out of memory error when I am trying to start to upload.